# Risk associated with Exchange email address as username when AD authentication is enabled

Tags: windows, email, active-directory, user-management

In my existing setup, we have Exchange Server joined with Windows Active Directory. Both the username and email address are the same for user accounts. Our support party also recommended using this approach.

But my Management questioned using the same email address as a computer login name. They told me that everyone, including third parties, knows the email address of the company.

When the email address is the same as the username, an attacker only needs to find the password. Management told me that our implementation reduces attacker workload by 50%. If the username is different from the email address, then the attacker needs to find both username and password.

But both my administrator and support team don't like this implementation because their workload will be increased. But their answer also not satisfactory to management. The support team said it is a standard.

What are the risks associated with this implementation or is this a secured approach?

Answer (score 1):

Management is expressing the risk of user enumeration and suggesting "security through obscurity" as a solution. A determined adversary will find this technique as nothing more than a speed bump. A better way to approach this is to identify:

1. **Excessive failed login attempts.** This is two fold since you need to identify any attempts to brute force an account. Where many passwords are used against a single user account. The other aspect is identifying password spraying where a single password is attempted against many user accounts or where these techniques are distributed across multiple IP addresses. Identifying and taking action against these techniques will be a significant win since there's virtually no way for the adversary to be successful. Where this technique really succeeds is when the adversary has unfettered access to go through their lengthy password lists. By limiting these attempts, it just isn't feasible for the adversary to guess a password.
2. **Logins from questionable IP addresses.** Many large companies offer this functionality where an alert is generated upon successful login from unknown locations. I would suggest sending the alert to a helpdesk account or your central IT to follow-up. This is because an adversary could delete the email while logged in. To get this reporting setup will take development cycles. Hopefully someone can offer a solution that I'm not aware of as it would be quite useful.

#### Risk from other Services

While your question was only for Exchange there are often other services/applications/websites within an organization. All of which could be a playground for an adversary to use the aforementioned techniques. There have been countless breach disclosures where a forgotten server in a closet was the entry point. So take inventory of services exposed to the public internet and ensure they have similar protections. Then continue to services only accessible to internal users. For internal services, identifying excessive failed logins is probably sufficient since access from an unknown IP wouldn't necessarily make sense. Note that I've seen user's go through a password change without updating cached service credentials and triggering alerts for failed logins. So beware of false-positives! That being said, identifying legitimate abuse of an internal service will be a sufficient indicator of compromise to invoke your incident response process.

#### WebsiteFailedLogins

Warning: shameless plug. I'm currently finishing up a significant re-write of [WebsiteFailedLogins](https://github.com/phbits/WebsiteFailedLogins). It's a PowerShell module, which leverages Logparser, to parse IIS logs (a component of Exchange) and identify excessive failed logins. Admittedly it's been many years since I've administered an Exchange server thanks to O365. However, I'm confident IIS will log the appropriate codes where this will be useful. Have a look at the [README](https://github.com/phbits/WebsiteFailedLogins/blob/main/README.md) and [Wiki](https://github.com/phbits/WebsiteFailedLogins/wiki) for more information as I think it would make a great fit!

Comment: Thanks for your comment. We have already implemented security against bruteforce. But Problem is social engineering attacks. We have integrated AD with VPN as well. All user names are same. Some how users can be victim of social engineering. They don't need to find computer user name. Actually we have reduce 50% of workload of attacker.

Comment: @web_guy how does social engineering factor in? how is that relevant to the scenario?

Comment: if this concept based on "security through obscurity." Why default user names are recommended to change? No problem with password changes. His question totally based on user name.

Comment: @Infra what authority recommends changing default usernames?

Comment: @schroeder i was reported audit team by two times for use default user name in windows server and firewall. First audit  was done under iso 9000, and most recent one, that mean last month, annual external audit team reported same issue. Actually last month i haven't used default name, finding was "user name  found word contain admin"...

Comment: @Infra but that doesn't answer my question. I've had auditors request all kinds of crazy things. What's the relevant standard? iso 9000 isn't a security standard and doesn't appear to be relevant here. What is being requested here absolutely is "security by obscurity"

Comment: @schroeder i agree with your point, still we didn't discuss about this report. Your point valuable for me. if they provide resources regarding this point i will post here.